# SuperNode Analysis on this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm trying to figure out all the equations of this circuit to find the value of \$V_x\$

[image]

I would like someone to verify the validity of my equations under the supernode method:
$$
2+ I = i\\
i=i_1 + i_2\\
i_2 + 1 = -i'\\
I' = i' + 2 
$$
also

$$ i_1 + i = 3V_x \\ 1 = V_x + i_1\\3V_x - i = 1 - V_x $$

Are these equations correct? I don't know how to find the current that goes through the line in the middle between node C and node B, and I think they are the same node because its the same voltage between them.

I furthermore fail to understand how to do the current-source transformation for the 1A generator.

Comment: Where is the supernode?

Comment: isnt it E? @G36

Comment: Your circuit contains only 4 nodes. Ground the bottom node (E). And you will left with only three nodes. But only two are unknown.

Comment: @G36 Yes, the nodes B and C are the same right? but what do you mean by unknown, from which context?

Comment: Yes, B and C is single (the same) node.

Comment: We do not know the voltage at nodes A and B. But we know the voltage at node D. VD = 1V. If the reference point is node E.

Comment: but my problem is how to use the supernode analysis method, if you could unveil it please

Comment: But in this case is not necessary to use the supernode so why do you even bother about it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148699/discussion-between-mohamed-salhi-and-g36).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your circuit if pick the bottom wire as a GND we are left with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1lIhC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see no supernode.

And the nodal equations for unknown node:

$$-1A + \frac{V_B}{1\Omega} + \frac{V_B - 1V}{1\Omega} + \frac{V_B - V_A}{1\Omega}=0 $$
And
$$V_A = 3V_X = 3 * \frac{1V - V_B}{1\Omega}$$

To get a supernode the GND needs to be at node B

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feMVex.png)</sup>

We have a supernode in a circuit because we have a voltage source between two nodes and none of those two nodes is GND. In fact we have two supernodes.

Thus, our equation will look like this:

$$1A + \frac{V_B}{1\Omega} +\frac{V_A}{1\Omega} + \frac{V_C}{1\Omega}= 0$$

As you can see we treat it as if we have one BIG (super) node.

And addtiotnal two eqationa are needet,
$$V_C - V_B = 1V$$
and
$$V_A - V_B = 3V_X = 3 * \frac{V_C}{1 \Omega}$$

And this is all we need.

Comment: infinite thanks G36, last  question please,   in the first equation (KCL) why did you write \$V_A / 1 \Omega \$ instead of \$ (V_A - V_b)/1 \Omega \$

Comment: For which resistor?

Comment: \$R_3 \$ please,

Comment: However the resistor R3 is not connected between the node Va and Vb. So why do you think that it should be ( (Va - VB)/R3 )?

Comment: it is , look at the circuit scheme (right to left)